# 301 Redirect vs. Rel=Canonical

Tags: url, seo, http-status-code-301, canonical-link

On our site, locale specific URLs are accessible across domains.

Say we have two URLs: `dog.aspx` (English) and `hund.aspx` (German).

The following URLs work:

- `www.example.com/hund.aspx` (displays English content, not German,but URL is German)
- `www.example.de/hund.aspx` (correct URL)

To solve this, we have two options:

- `www.example.com/hund.aspx` redirect to `www.example.com/dog.aspx`
- Have `canonical` URL in `www.example.com/hund.aspx` to `www.example.com/dog.aspx`

What is more preferable? **301 redirect or `canonical` URL?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 301 redirect is preferable to a `canonical` declaration.

User agents can’t bypass redirects, while `canonical` is only an advice which a) not all user agents support, and b) even user agents that support it don’t *have* to follow it.

RFC 6596 [recommends](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6596#section-5) this, too:

> Before adding the canonical link relation, verification of the following is RECOMMENDED:
>
> 1. […]
> 2. For HTTP, permanent HTTP redirects (Section 10.3.2 of [RFC2616]), the traditional strong indicator that a IRI's content has been permanently moved, could not be implemented in place of the canonical link relation.
> 3. […]

Answer (score 0):

The Cananical URL is only when the content is identical and to avoid any duplicate content penalties from google. Since the content is in a different language, this isn't identical so this isn't a issue.

It sounds like what you are after is the hreflang tag. You can read up more about how to implement it [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=189077)

Basically you would use something like this:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="www.abc.de/hund.aspx" />
```

`<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-us" href="www.abc.com/hund.aspx" />`

Comment: But the content is duplicate since both the URLs point to the same content i.e. www.abc.com/dog.aspx and www.abc.com/hund.aspx both display the english version.

Answer (score 0):

Use 301 redirect which passes more link juice than canonical. It's a duplicate content with different URL, redirect will solve it perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using both  301 redirect and hreflang tag, it isn't a content issue as the same content is in a different language but a redirect would help. It is important to have a hreflang tag in place as the content is in German and English.