# If I change my SEO-friendly URLs, how do I tell Google to forget the old ones?

Tags: url, seo, google-search

I have an ecommerce site with over 3000 products. Currently, my URLs look like this:

```
http://www.muszakiarena.hu/termekek/sencor-sle-1958-led-tv/3112
```

Now, 'termekek' means 'products', the second one is the name of the product, while the 3rd one is the ID of the product.

I want to remove 'termekek' from the URLs, because it is unneccessary and I hope I'll get better rankings without it. So new URLs would look like

```
http://www.muszakiarena.hu/sencor-sle-1958-led-tv/3112
```

Now, the system already works this way (the product pages show up at  `www.muszakiarena.hu/sencor-sle-1958-led-tv/3112`), but if I change my product links in the navigation to the new type and ask Google to recrawl, I'm afraid it will detect duplicate content.

How do I tell Google to forget the old URLs and only keep the new ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should redirect (with [`301`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301)) from the old to the new URLs.

That way all search engines that indexed the pages under the old URLs will learn that the URLs changed as soon as they try to crawl them again. The same goes for users that bookmarked/published the old URLs: when visiting them, they get redirected to the new URL.

If using a 301 redirect is not possible in your case, you can use the [`canonical` link type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element). ([But a 301 redirect is preferable.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13309386/1591669))

Comment: I added this to my code

if ($url[1]=='termekek')  {
    
  header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: http://www.muszakiarena.hu/".$url[2]."/".$url[3]);
    //echo "Location: http://www.muszakiarena.hu/".$url[2]."/"+$url[3];
exit();
    
}